# How do i place elements in this php array 1 index further?

Tags: php, arrays

I have to make a little script for a school assignment which places the days of the week in chronological order with an index in front of them. Although Sunday has to be the first day and therefore must have the number 1 in front of it. (2 Monday, 3 Tuesday etc.)

I have tried to do this by placing all the elements in the array one index further but it does not seem to work.

```
$myArray = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday");
for ($i=0; $i<count($myArray); $i++) {
  $myArray[$i] = $myArray[$i+1];
  echo ($i+1) . " " . $myArray[$i] . "<br>";
}
```

And here is the error message i get when i execute the code:

1 Tuesday
2 Wednesday
3 Thursday
4 Friday
5 Saturday
6 Sunday

> Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in C:\xampp\htdocs\opdracht_22.php on line 13
>   7

The result i am trying to get is:

1 Sunday
2 Monday
3 Tuesday
4 Wednesday
5 Thursday
6 Friday
7 Saturday

Is there anything i am missing here? How can i improve my code?

Comment: Instead of `monday, tuesday, ...`, why didn't you store them in the correct way, like `sunday, monday,...`?

Comment: The first state of the array needs to remain this way. I cannot change it so that Sunday would be the first index.

Comment: Can you just copy task here as your explanation is unclear.

Comment: I guess what they want you to do is take the last element from the array, remove it from the array and push it back at the beginning of the array. Not going to do your homework for you though.

Comment: array_pop, array_unshift, http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php RTFM

Comment: @JonathanLagenhorst I've added an answer. The underlying logic would not be that difficult to understand.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Too bad he/she needs to learn.

Comment: @E_p I am really trying to learn php. I am not just doing this to get my homework done. I make websites with html and bootstrap css and figured php would be good to learn

Comment: @RST I am really trying to learn php. I am not just doing this to get my homework done. I make websites with html and bootstrap css and figured php would be good to learn.

Comment: @E_p Sorry, didn't know what else to put there to him/her understand the underlying logic. Now I've added comments at the relevant places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result using simple `while` loop,

```
<?php
    $myArray = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday");
    $array_length = count($myArray);  // $array_length is 7
    $index = $array_length - 1;  // $index is 6 here 
    $counter = 1;  // here $counter is used to print Nth weekday
    while(true){
        echo $counter . " " . $myArray[$index] . "<br />";
        $index = ($index + 1) % $array_length;  // performs increment and modulus operation to get the reminder value
        ++$counter;
        if($index == $array_length - 1){  // whenever $index is 6 again the loop will terminate
            break;
        }
    }
?>
```

Output:

```
1 Sunday
2 Monday
3 Tuesday
4 Wednesday
5 Thursday
6 Friday
7 Saturday
```

Comment: It took me a while to understand, but i do understand this piece of code now :p. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @JonathanLagenhorst I've added comments also. Now it should not be that difficult to grab the logic. :)

Comment: @JonathanLagenhorst If your learning PHP, there is bad practice in this code. One often made mistake in loops is counting array length in each cycle. You have the same error in your initial code. The array length doesn't change here so there is no need to count length over and over. Store the length in a variable  and set `$index` equal to this variable.

Comment: @RST Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: @RST Ah, good point. It's a negligible performance issue for small arrays but can be a time consuming task for large arrays. I've updated my answer.

Comment: This question is stated to be a school assignment. IMHO this is still a wrong answer. The teacher will not be convinced @JonathanLagenhorst put it together himself (knowing he wasn't able to solve/understand the error on the non-existing index). A simpler solution, move Sunday to the beginning, and create a counter related to the index while printing (like he does in his sample code) would be more convincing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
    <?php
        $myArray = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday");
        foreach($myArray as $key => $val) {
           echo $key++ . " " . $val . "<br>";
        }  
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: I would go `foreach` and `sprintf` for formatting. Or at least put `count` outside of loop.

Comment: I cannot do that. The array must be like ("Monday", "Tuesday" etc.). I have to change it using code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a temporary array and swap them across.

Such as:

```
  $newArray = [];
  for($i = 0; $i < count($myArray); $i++){
     $newArray[$i+1] = $myArray[$i];
  }

  $newArray[0] = $newArray[$i]; // for the last one to loop back to the first element of the temporary array
```

Then just copy the elements of newArray to myArray

```
  $myArray = $newArray;
```

Let me know how it goes

Comment: If this worked for you, please mark it as the correct answer grma

Answer (score 0):

After moving Sunday to the beginning, one easy way to reorder the keys is to use array_combine with a range for the new keys.

```
array_unshift($myArray, array_pop($myArray));
array_combine(range(1,7), $myArray);
```

Comment: I will save this code for later if i have learned a little more about php. I started this week with php and i am still really new to this language :').